# Issue with malicious files showing up in IIS site folders

Tags: iis, networking, service

If this is something in another thread I'm happy to read but I've been keeping google hot without a result.

I have an IIS site that is getting hammered with some search engine exploit file creations. Basically trying to direct traffic to videos on YouTube by getting them indexed. I've disabled all FTP accounts to start and then went through confirming everything is updated including things like PHP. I'm having a bear of a time figuring out where these are coming from. I have started resetting the passwords on the anonymous user credential for each website but I don't think this is a password exploit.

The info I have:

- They all seem to be created by Network Service but I can't tell which site they are coming in through.
- I'm using up to date and active AV and active malware scanning.
- All windows updates are in place
- I have attempted to use process monitor and the only thing I can see is that the file creation comes from NETWORK SERVICE

The only thing I've thought of at this point is an exploit somewhere but without any viruses, missing updates or malware I'm at a loss of where to go with this.

I have tried to put auditing in place but this server has a pretty immense load overall so there is a number of completely safe temp files created and deleted constantly. This is compounded by the files being created at random times. I may keep a clean deck for a day or two and then get hit for a few hours. I did try auditing anyways and stopped at 15gb of security events without a hit.

I am considering containerizing into credentialed app pools but that will be a pretty significant time and resource overhead for a guess.

Any ideas or suggestions? I'm nearing the point of visiting a fortune teller down the road to see if they have any idea. :D

Comment: 1) Each app pools should have its own identity so that you can know for sure which is hacked. 2) By default you only give read/execute permissions to the pool identities on web content folders, so why did you grant write permission? 3) Once you learn which site/pool create those files, it would require further analysis of that site to locate the security risk. Hire a security consultant and that should speed things up.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that this response came through. Great suggestions and I'll respond once I have either more questions or a resolution to report.